pentaho dataintegration text file input
I want to read data row 1,2,3 into column, please teach me
enter image description here
I want to insert data row to column:
Start Date  End Date   Report Type  Currency Storefront Name Apple Identifier
12/30/2022  02/02/2023 Apple Music  USD      US              696611253


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
